Can the analytic extension of the harmonic series be expressed in terms of elementary functions?
I have been wondering whether it is possible to extend the harmonic series function $H(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1/k)$ to an infinitely differentiable (and possibly analytic) function $H$ over the reals, hopefully in such a way so that the harmonic series' defining difference equation $H(n+1)-H(n)=1/(n+1)$ continues to hold when $n$ is replaced by a noninteger.
I figured out that I could do just that by first noting that for each positive integer $n$, we have $\frac{1}{n}=\int_{t=0}^1(t^{n-1}dt)$.
Thus, we have $H(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{t=0}^1(t^{k-1}dt)=\int_{t=0}^1\sum_{k=1}^{n}t^{k-1}dt=\int_{t=0}^1(\frac{1-t^n}{1-t}dt)$.
Now, I simply replace $n$ with an arbitrary real number $x$ to get $H(x)=\int_{t=0}^1(\frac{1-t^x}{1-t}dt)$.
This integral converges for all $x>-1$, so this extends the harmonic series to all real numbers greater than $-1$.
This function I noted indeed satisfies the difference equation $H(x+1)-H(x)=1/(x+1)$ for all $x>-1$.
I realized that this function can also be extended to values strictly less than $-1$ by using this difference relation to work backwards: that is, for instance, I assign $H(-3/2)$ to be the value $H(-1/2)-\frac{1}{-1/2}=H(-1/2)+2$, and so on.
This extends the harmonic series function $H$ to all real numbers except the negative integers (where $H$ clearly has poles).
I noted this function is indeed infinitely differentiable at all these values:  For $x>-1$, the $n$th derivative is simply $\int_{t=0}^1\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(\frac{1-t^x}{1-t})dt$, while for $x< -1$, the $n$th derivative may be derived from those for $x > -1$ via the difference equation $H^{(n)}(x+1)-H^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^nn!/(x+1)^{n+1}$ (gotten by differentiating the original difference equation $n$ times).
I believe the function $H$ is also analytic at all these values, making this a true analytic extension of the harmonic series function which preserves the defining difference equation of the series.
The question I have is whether this function $H$ can be expressed in terms of only elementary functions (such as exp and log). I have tried to solve the integral $\int_{t=0}^1(\frac{1-t^x}{1-t}dt)$ exactly using various methods like integration by parts, but all those efforts proved unsuccessful. My guess is that it isn't possible, but I wanted your thoughts.

Look up the digamma function

For rational arguments it will reduce to elementary functions. Beyond that for arbitrary reals, no.
